# Does TLSv1.2 support 3DES

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl

I wanted to know if I configure my openssl server to explicitly use TLSv1.2, the do I have to also mention not to use 3DES (by adding "!3DES" to the string), or the expicit use of TLSv1.2 remove the support of 3DES.

From [this](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html) link I can see that TLS1.2 does not have 3DES in their available cipher list. So I guess it does not support?

The string I am using is `"HIGH+TLSv1.2:!MD5:!SHA1"`

Comment: Why do you want to remove 3DES support? Most browsers today will use the stronger ciphers anyway.

Comment: @NathanC It is for some standard compliance.

Comment: Removing it is considered best practice by some - e.g. https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2016/11/16/announcing-ssl-labs-grading-changes-for-2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLS 1.2 can be used with any ciphers defined for SSL 3.0 and later. This includes 3DES (DES-CBC3) ciphers. What [you refer to](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html) is not a list which ciphers are usable with which SSL/TLS version but with which SSL/TLS version a cipher was introduced.

Proof:

```
terminal_1 $ openssl s_server -cipher '3DES' -cert cert.pem -key key.pem
...
terminal_2 $ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:4433
...
Protocol  : TLSv1.2
Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
...
```

More proof: The [TLS 1.2 standard (RFC 5246)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt) lists in appendix A.5 lots of ciphers usable with TLS 1.2, which includes several 3DES ciphers.

> The string I am using is "HIGH+TLSv1.2:!MD5:!SHA1"

With this cipher string you allow only ciphers which were introduced with TLS 1.2. Since no new 3DES ciphers were added with TLS 1.2 no 3DES ciphers will be used with this string. But, no TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 client will be able to connect to the server since none of the ciphers you offer is supported by these older clients. While modern browser all support TLS 1.2 some applications still don't. This is true especially for older Java applications or for OpenSSL based applications on Mac OS X, since this is shipping with a very old version of OpenSSL.

Answer (score -1):

You're right, TLSv1.2 does not have DES support in it:

```
$ openssl ciphers -tls1 -v | grep TLSv1.2
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
AES256-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/RSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
AES128-GCM-SHA256       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
AES128-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
```

You don't have to explicitly deny DES because it won't be available with the older suites disabled.

Comment: This is 1st wrong and 2nd DES is not the same as 3DES

Comment: Openssl often shows "DES" in the cipher list when it means 3DES.

Comment: @DanPritts: it shows DES-CBC3 for 3DES as in DES-CBC3-SHA. With DES it shows instead DES-CBC as in DES-CBC-SHA.

Comment: OP is explicitly disabling TLS1.1 and older. 1.2 does not include DES/DES3 cipher suites and thus doesn't have to be disabled. I do not see any DES ciphers in my output.